# Apache spark with python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read a spark dataframe using python and then convert the spark dataframe to pandas dataframe then convert the pandas dataframe back to spark dataframe ( after doing some data analysis) . Please suggest.

Comment: they are very compatible, e.g. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame

Comment: Suggest what? What did you try, what's wrong with it, why does it fail,etc. #grumpycat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend you to take your time and read carefully the Spark's documentation, focusing in the `Pyspark` implementation, because it has more examples than others.

Easy, if you read the documentation of [SQLContext.createDataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sqlcontext#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame), you can see that they can receive as data the next structures:

```
createDataFrame(data, schema=None, samplingRatio=None)
```

> data – an RDD of Row/tuple/list/dict, list, or pandas.DataFrame.

Besides, if you read the documentation related to [DataFrames](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sqlcontext#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas), you will notice they have a method called `toPandas`, and it allows to to convert spark's `DataFrame`s into `Pandas`.